# Completion of $\mathscr{P} [a,b]$

Tags: polynomials, metric-spaces

The space of polynomials  $(\mathscr{P} [a,b] , d)$ is not complete, where $d$ is a metric $$d(f(x),g(x)) = sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|: x\in [a,b]\}$$ , so to complete it I consider the cauchy sequences of polynomials (procedure applied in cauchy-weierstrass construction of real numbers).
But the problem is when I consider these equivalence class, how should I treat them as continuous function because after completion I know that it should be isomorphic to $ C [a,b]$; also what are the other possible  ways to complete it.

Comment: Are you sure ? $f_n(x) = x^n$ does not converge to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @N.H. It's also not a Cauchy sequence.  What's your point?

Comment: @RobertIsrael : sorry my comment was useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[\{P_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}]$ be one equivalence class with the Cauchy sequence  $\{P_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ as its representative:

Now define $f: [a,b] \to \Bbb R$ with $f(x) := \lim_{ n \to +\infty} P_{n}(x)$.

Show that $f$ is not depended to  any representative of the equivalence class $[\{P_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}]$, and  $f \in C[a,b].$

Answer (score 1):

By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, all continuous functions on $[a,b]$ are uniform limits of polynomials.  Also, the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ is a continuous function.  So the completion is indeed $C[a,b]$.

Comment: But how do I go from P[a,b] to C[a,b]